# How do you match percent symbols in rewrite rules?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am redirecting URLs for a website, and have the following URL to match and redirect:

```
example.com/test-string-%2526-more-string/
```

However, I cannot match the %2526 portion of the string - it seems that Apache is treating the percentage symbol as a special character, and escaping it seems to make no difference. Here's the basic rule I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^test-string-\%2526-more-string/?$ /new-location.htm [R=301,L,NC]
```

With or without the escaping slash, this rule doesn't fire. I suspect the problem is with how apache processes encoded characters in URLs - %25 translates to a percentage symbol itself, so could Apache be translating "%25" to "%" before running the rule? Or is something else going on?

Comment: this has nothing to do with unicode, but with urlencoding

Comment: Sorry, yes, have fixed my wording.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experimented with lots of rewrite rules and in the end just went with this:

```
RewriteRule ^test-string-\%26-more-string/?$ /new-location.htm [R=301,L,NC]
```

So the `%25` was converted to a `%` symbol.